# How do you migrate questions?

Tags: support, migration

I have seen questions over SO that have comments saying thing like: "not a good question for this site - migrated it to SuperUser" - what does this mean?

I am quite new to SO and haven't found out about many features on it. Please can you not roar at me, which, unfortunately, my parents do most of the time.

Comment: Its part of the closure workflow - All sites have a specific set of sites you can close/migrate a question to. It can be closed by regular users with sufficient rep, or a mod. Mods can migrate anywhere.